# Finding all the elements in a list between two elements (not using index, and with wrap around)

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to figure out a way to find all the elements that appear between two list elements (inclusive) - but to do it without reference to position, and instead with reference to the elements themselves. It's easier to explain with code:

I have a list like this:

```
['a','b','c','d','e']
```

And I want a function that would take, two arguments corresponding to elements eg. `f('a','d')`, and return the following:

```
['a','b','c','d']
```

I'd also like it to wrap around, eg. `f('d','b')`:

```
['d','e','a','b']
```

I'm not sure how to go about coding this. One hacky way I've thought of is duplicating the list in question (`['a','b','c','d','e','a','b','c','d','e']`) and then looping through it and flagging when the first element appears and when the last element does and then discarding the rest - but it seems like there would be a better way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are the values unique?

Comment: Yes, in the case I'm looking to solve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def foo(a, b):
    s, e = [a.index(x) for x in b]
    if s <= e:
        return a[s:e+1]
    else:
        return a[s:] + a[:e+1]

print(foo(['a','b','c','d','e'], ['a', 'd']))  # --> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

print(foo(['a','b','c','d','e'], ['d', 'b']))  # --> ['d', 'e', 'a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 0):

So the following obviously needs error handling as indicated below, and also, note the the index() function only takes the index of the first occurrence. You have not specified how you want to handle duplicate elements in the list.

```
def f(mylist, elem1, elem2):
    posn_first = mylist.index(elem1) # what if it's not in the list?
    posn_second = mylist.index(elem2) # ditto
    if (posn_first <= posn_second):
        return mylist[posn_first:posn_second+1]
    else:
        return mylist[posn_first:] + mylist[:posn_second+1]
```

Answer (score -2):

This would be a simple approach, given you always want to use the first appearence of the element in the list:

```
def get_wrapped_values(input_list, start_element, end_element):
    return input_list[input_list.index(start_element): input_list.index(end_element)+1]
```

Comment: I guess you wanted to use ":" instead of "," in your code, but it still doesn't work for wrap around

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have run it first ...
The +1 was also inside the brackets although it should be outside. I should really be more attentive, even for relatively easy questions like this... It works now.